# Function to clean up character variables doesn't work when source from a different file (R 3.2.3 - Windows 10)

Tags: r, string, function

I have a data set with many bad encoded french characters in different variables (column). For exemple:

```
region <- c("MontrÃ©al", "Sherbrooke")
statut <- c("TerminÃ©", "Partiellement")
foo <- as.data.frame(cbind(region, statut))
```

So I wrote the next two functions to find and replace all the bad characters:

```
replaceFrench <- function(chr.col){
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã©", "e", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã¨", "e", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã´", "o", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã‰", "E", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã¢", "A", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã§", "c", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã€", "A", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("Ã", "a", chr.col)
  chr.col <- gsub("\\s+", " ", chr.col)
  chr.col
}


replaceFrenchAll <- function(df){
 for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
   if (class(df[,i]) == "factor" | class(df[,i]) == "character") {
    df[,i] <- replaceFrench(df[,i])
    df[,i] <- as.factor(df[,i])
   }
 }
 df
}
```

When i tried to 'source' these functions from another .r file, the function still return the bad encoded character.

```
source(clean-french-letters.R)

replaceFrenchAll(foo)

   region       statut
1  MontrÃ©al    TerminÃ©
2  Sherbrooke   Partiellement
```

But when the data and the functions are written in the same .r file, the output is correct:

```
replaceFrenchAll(foo)

   region       statut
1  Montreal     Termine
2  Sherbrooke   Partiellement
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

I work with R studio Version 0.99.891 and R 3.2.3 on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with R 3.2.3 or 3.3.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Btw you can use something like `iconv`:  `sapply(foo, iconv, from = "UTF-8", to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")` or `sapply(foo, iconv, from = "UTF-8")`

Comment: I tried with the `inconv` function inside `sapply` and now it work. Thanks for the reply!